# Secuencia de retornos incorrecta usando async/await

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando comprender como funciona `await`/`async`. He leido varias opiniones que vienen a decir

> `async`/`await` no es mas que una *syntax-sugar* sobre las *Promises*.

Sin embargo, el resultado que estoy obteniendo **choca frontalmente** con esto: no soy capaz de explicar las salidas del siguiente código (tomado originalmente [de aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/8663418)).

```js
function sleep( ms ) {
  return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, ms ) );
}

async function demo( ) {
  console.log( 'Taking a break...' );
  await sleep( 2000 );
  console.log( 'Two seconds later' );
}

async function demo2( ) {
  console.log( 'demo2 -> before' );
  await demo( );
  console.log( 'demo2 -> after' );
}

function demo3( ) {
  console.log( 'demo3 -> before' );
  demo2( );
  console.log( 'demo3 -> after' );
}

demo3( );
```

El resultado obtenido es:

> demo3 -> before
>   demo2 -> before
>   Taking a break...
>   demo3 -> after
>   ... pausa de 2 segundos ...
>   Two seconds later
>   demo2 -> after

**Sin embargo**, el resultado **esperado** es este otro:

> demo3 -> before
>   demo2 -> before
>   Taking a break...
>   Two seconds later
>   demo2 -> after
>   demo3 -> after

De algún modo que no comprendo, el uso de `async`/`await` ¡ **cambia el orden** de las retornos ! No se me ocurre ninguna forma, usando solo *callbacks* y *closures*, que provoque ese comportamiento.

Por las salidas, **parece** que la función `demo3( )` retorna **antes** que la función `demo2( )`, lo cual es sencillamente imposible según el modo de ejecución *clásico* que yo conozco.

¿ Como funciona **realmente** `async`/`await` ? ¿ Realmente es **solo** una *facilidad* para usar *Promises* ? ¿ Me estoy *liando* yo mismo buscando `los 3 pies del gato` ?

Comment: De alguien a quien le gusta buscarle 3 pies al gato, ¡No entiendo porqué siempre encuentro más de lo que busco! ¿Será porqué el gato tiene *por lo general* 4 pies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Voy a quitar el *azúcar sintáctico* de tu código para que se vea claro qué se está haciendo:

```js
//se queda como está
function sleep( ms ) {
  return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, ms ) );
}

function demoNoSugar() {
  console.log( 'Taking a break...' );
  let promesa = sleep(2000);
  return promesa.then(() => console.log( 'Two seconds later' ));
}


function demo2NoSugar() {
  console.log( 'demo2 -> before' );
  let promesa = demoNoSugar();
  return promesa.then(()=> console.log( 'demo2 -> after' ));
}

function demo3NoSugar( ) {
  console.log( 'demo3 -> before' );
  demo2NoSugar( )
  console.log( 'demo3 -> after' );
}

demo3NoSugar( );
```

Pasos:

1. Ejecuta `demo3NoSugar`, que pone en consola `'demo3 -> before'`.
2. Ejecuta `demo2NoSugar`, que pone en consola `'demo2 -> before'`.
3. Ejecuta `demoNoSugar`, que pone en consola `'Taking a break...'`.
4. Ejecuta `sleep(2000)`, que devuelve una promesa que se resolverá en 2 segundos. Antes de devolverla se le *adjunta* en `demoNoSugar` la orden de escribir `'Two seconds later'` al resolverse.
5. A la resolución de esa promesa se le añade otra orden de escribir `'demo2 -> after'` en `demo2NoSugar` y se devuelve de nuevo.
6. Estamos de nuevo en `demo3NoSugar`, que no *captura* la promesa (es decir, ignora lo que devuelve la llamada `demo2NoSugar` y no usa `await` para esperar) e inmediatamente termina escribiendo en consola `'demo3 -> after'`.
7. La promesa se resuelve  al pasar los 2000 milisegundos y se escriben los dos mensajes *adjuntos*.

Cosas a tener en cuenta:

Una función que tenga un `async`, devuelve siempre una `Promise`. Igualmente, una función que devuelva una `Promise`, se puede considerar que es `async` (y por tanto se puede usar con `await`):

```js
async function devuelve1() {
  return 1;
}

function devuelve2() {
  return new Promise(res => res(2));
}

let p1 = devuelve1();
p1.then(r => console.log(r));


async function aux() {
  let r = await devuelve2();
  console.log(r);
}

aux();
```

Answer (score 7):

Es porque no estás usando **await** con **demo2()**

```js
function sleep( ms ) {
  return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, ms ) );
}

async function demo( ) {
  console.log( 'Taking a break...' );
  await sleep( 2000 );
  console.log( 'Two seconds later' );
}

async function demo2( ) {
  console.log( 'demo2 -> before' );
  await demo( );
  console.log( 'demo2 -> after' );
}

async function demo3( ) {
  console.log( 'demo3 -> before' );
  await demo2( );
  console.log( 'demo3 -> after' );
}

demo3( );
```

Como podrás en la consola tienes:

```
demo3 -> before
demo2 -> before
Taking a break...
Two seconds later
demo2 -> after
demo3 -> after
```

El await, solamente *no debes usarlo*, para la función que ejecutas desde el **main** (en este caso el llamado a demo3)

Comment: De hecho no *puedes usarlo* fuera de una función async

Comment: Entonces, si uso una librería externa, ¿ tengo que saber si todas sus funciones son o no `async` antes de poder llamarlas ? ¿ Y usar `await` cada vez que las llame ?

Comment: En caso de que sean async, si.
Pero es lo mismo que te pasa con las promises, tienes que saber cuales lo son y usar el then()/catch()