# Como hacer para que el javascript espere la ejecución a la llamada API a una función PHP

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un problemilla, tengo un fichero javascript que necesito de varios datos para hacer una llamada api a un fichero php, uno de los datos que necesito, lo obtengo en otra llamada api a otra función php. Por mucho que ponga waits (haciendo la función), no consigo que la segunda función (la que necesito de los datos de la primera), espere a obtener los datos de la primera llamada, de tal forma que hago console.log y veo como primero se ejecuta la segunda función con ese dato vacio, y luego se muestra el dato que se ha recogido de la primera función, por ejemplo.

```
var primeraVariable = return api.call('GET','/primeraFuncion');
```

Para la segunda llamada, necesito var primeraVariable

```
var segundaVariable = return api.call('GET','/segundaFuncion', primeraVariable);
```

Pues resulta que a la hora de hacer la segunda variable, la variable "primeraVariable" está vacía (suponiendo que se declara al principio y demás, es solo un ejemplo), ya que obtiene el valor mas tarde, y quiero que no se haga la segunda variable hasta que no esté la primera.

Espero haberme entendido.

Saludos.

Comment: puedes usar una [llamada asincrona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada decirte que Javascript es un lenguaje de programación *asíncrono*, o sea, que existe código que tal que

```js
    var valorUno = instruccionUno();
    var valorDos = instruccionDos();
    console.log(valorUno + valorDos);
```

no te pueda dar seguridad de que `instruccionUno()` se ejecute antes que `instruccionDos`. Peor aun, de que tenga sentido la suma de lo que retornen.

No todo es asincrono, pero las llamadas a una api si que lo son.

En tu caso debes hacer, si es que `api.call` retorna una promesa

```js
api.call('GET','/primeraFuncion').then(function (response) {
   var primeraVariable = response;
   api.call('GET','/segundaFuncion', primeraVariable).then(function (response) {
     var segundaVariable = response;
   });
});
```

O si acepta un [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) debera ser un poco diferente

Te animo a que leas sobre javascript asincrono y callbacks para entender.

Ya si puedes, usar [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) mucho mejor.

Saludos

Comment: Al final lo arreglé haciendolo que desde php, la llamada "var primeraVariable = return api.call('GET','/primeraFuncion');" la hago internamente desde php sino existe un parametro y me ha funcionado correctamente. No obstante, leeré sobre ello a ver si lo cambio.