# ¿Qué papel desempeñan async y await en una función?

Tags: javascript, function, async-await

¿Qué es y para qué sirve el **async** y el **await** en la siguiente función?:

```
async function getMessages() {
    const messages = await Model.find();
    return messages;
}
```

Comment: this omit to use the "then" step on promise and then wait the response before return the value.. ( A bit explanation )

Comment: Relacionado: [Diferencias entre callback, Promises y async/await](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qué-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await)

Answer (score 3):

La declaración de `async` y `await` generan una función asíncrona, es decir que por dentro siguen trabajando con *promesas*, recordando que estas pasan por alguno de los estados siguientes:

- resolved
- rejected
- pending

Si observamos esta línea:

```
const messages = await Model.find();
```

Generará que la función se pause esperando que el método `find()` devuelva una respuesta que pudiera tener alguno de los estados antes mencionados, una vez hecho lo anterior continuará la ejecución de la misma y retornará el resultado de la promesa en:

```
return messages;
```

Te coloco este ejemplo:

```
function potencia() {
  return 10000 ** 2
}

async function obtenPotencia() {
  const respuesta =  await potencia()
  return respuesta
}
```

Si le hacemos un `console.log()` a la función asíncrona nos devolverá esto:

> [object Promise] { ... }

Dado lo anterior necesitamos acceder al resultado de la promesa a través de:

- `then` que nos entregará el resultado de dicha acción; aquí puede quedar en el estado de **resolved()**
- `catch` obtendrá el mensaje de error por el cual la promesa quedó en el estado de **rejected** y no logró resolverse de manera satisfactoria **(si es que se presenta este caso)**

**EJEMPLO**

Ahora para obtener el estado que nos devolvió lo anterior tenemos este fragmento de código:

```
obtenPotencia().then((respuestaFuncion) => {
                console.log(response)
             }).catch((respuestaFuncion) =>{
                console.log(`Algo salió mal: ${respuestaFuncion}`)
             })
```

Donde a la función asíncrona le encadenamos ambos métodos para controlar la eventual respuesta que pudieramos estar recibiendo.

**Caso 1**

Si por ejemplo le cambio el nombre a la constante `respuesta` a `respuestas`, obtendría un resultado como este en pantalla al ejecutar el código:

> "Algo salió mal: respuestas is not defined"

La promesa devolvió un **rejected** por que el nombre de la constante cambió y no coincide.

En cambio si respetamos la escritura de la constante, obtenemos esto:

> 100000000

**Ejemplo completo**

```js
    function potencia() {
      return 10000 ** 2
    }
    
    async function obtenPotencia() {
      const respuesta =  await potencia()
      return respuesta
    }
    
    obtenPotencia().then((respuestaFuncion) => {
                    console.log(`El resultado es: ${respuestaFuncion}`)
                 }).catch((respuestaFuncion) =>{
                    console.log(`Algo salió mal: ${respuestaFuncion.message}`)
                 })
```

**Referencias para construir respuesta**

- [Async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)
- [catch promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/catch)