# Signal Async Completion - Error en Gulp

Tags: javascript, nodejs, gulp, asynctask

Hola estoy aprendiendo a utilizar gulp, pero en la consola sucede un error de la cual no tengo ni idea. Estuve probando este simple código:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('tarea1', () => {
    console.log("hola mundo");
});
```

pero luego en la consola se refiere a un tema de asincronía. Incluso es el mismo código de donde estoy aprendiendo gulp.

[image: muestra del error de async]

**¿A qué se refiere con el tema sincronía y como puedo solucionarlo?**. Busque en la documentación pero no entiendo del todo, por eso acudo aquí. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se completa una tarea, ésta debe avisar de que ha terminado, [usando un callback](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task). Es algo similar a las promesas: al ser las tareas ejecutadas de manera asíncrona, gulp necesita saber cuando han sido completadas mediante la señal producida por la llamada a esta función.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('tarea1', callback => {
    console.log("hola mundo");
    callback();
});
```

Comment: Lectura extra para saber más de asincronía en JS: [promesas, callbacks y async](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await/)