# Obtener valor de Promesa

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo.

```js
const prueba = async (valor) => {
    return await valor;
};

function testP(){
   return prueba("prueba");
}

console.log(testP());
```

Al imprimirlo en pantalla me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero acceder al PromiseResult y devolverlo, pero no estoy pudiendo hacerlo.

Comment: Async function testp(){return await prueba();}

Comment: Al hacer eso, me da el mismo problema

Comment: Tal vez [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await) te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de `async` y `await` facilita el tratar las promesas, pero hay que aclarar algunos conceptos: una función asíncrona **siempre** devuelve una promesa, aunque su lógica no requiera realmente asincronía:

```js
//prueba es una función async, por tanto siempre devuelve una promesa
const prueba = async (valor) => {
    return await valor; //aquí await es innecesario, no hace nada
};


function testP(){
   return prueba("prueba"); //devuelves la promesa que se generó en prueba
}

console.log(testP()); //intenta imprimir una promesa

testP().then(valor => console.log('tengo el valor', valor));

async function testP2() {
  let resultado = await prueba("prueba2");
  console.log("dentro de la función asíncrona tengo",resultado);
  return resultado; //la función es asíncrona, se vuelve a meter en una promesa
}

console.log("tengo una promesa de nuevo", testP2());
```