# plantear función de otra forma

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de entender como funcionan las funciones callback y las funciones flechas y para eso he estado intentando convertir esta función en 2 funciones 'SEPARADAS' y que una llame a la otra, pero hasta ahora sin poder lograrlo. he visto ejemplo con solo 1 parámetro, desconozco si es que realmente se puede hacer con 2 parámetros.
muchas gracias.

```js
let array = function (a, b) {
  return a.filter(x => b.indexOf(x) === -1);
};
console.log(array([1, 2, 2], [2]));
```

Comment: Me encantaría ayudarte con esta pregunta Nelson, me recuerda a mi mismo tratando de comprender este tipo de conceptos. Sería de mucha ayuda que escribas las 2 funciones **por separado** y nos cuentes cuál es el comportamiento esperado y qué planeas hacer con más detalle; porque siendo honesto me cuesta entenderte y poder ver en dónde está el problema. Con estos detalles con gusto de doy una respuesta concisa para que aprendas. También te recomiendo que leas [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await/277693#277693).

Answer (score 3):

No hay necesidad de enredarse tanto, de hecho tienes un error de conceptos, puesto que una `funcion callback` y una `funcion flecha` son realmente lo mismo, de hecho comparar ambas es **absurdo**, ademas normalmente nunca se dice:

**funcion callback**, se dice simplemente **callback**.

Y ojo, antes de que me quemen en la hoguera por decir que una `funcion callback` y una `funcion flecha` son lo mismo, yo a lo que me refiero cuando digo que son iguales **NO** me refiero a su funcion **NI** su forma de usarse, si no a la **concepcion de funciones** como tal, es decir, quizas hayas pensado en algun momento algo asi como que `callback` y `funcion flechas` son tipos de funciones distintos entre si, lo cual **es erroneo**.

Para que aquellos usuarios mas avanzados me entiendan realmente lo que trato de decir, es por ejemplo si nosotros hacemos una comparacion entre una `funcion`:

```
function mi_funcion(){
   //Codigo
}
```

Y un generador:

```
function* mi generador(){
   //Codigo
}
```

Estos dos conceptos `SI` son de diferentes casos, pues un generador esta diseñado para usarse de otra manera diferente a las funciones comunes.

Aqui lo que realmente difiere entre `callback`, una `funcion` y una `funcion flecha` es la forma de su utilización, aunque para el caso de la `funcion` y `funcion flecha` hay otra distincion mas que hacer, y es que una `funcion normal` tiene contexto (puedes usar `this`), una `funcion flecha` **NO** tiene contexto, `this` nunca hara alusion a la `funcion flecha`.

Pues el concepto de callback es tan sencillo de definir como esto:

> callback: funcion que es pasada como parametro a otra funcion.

Ahora bien, ten en cuenta que segun esta definicion **NO** le puedes llamar callback a una `funcion normal` como es esta:

```
function mi_funcion(){
   
}

mi_funcion();
```

Esto debido a que no cumple dos de los requisitos:

- La funcion no recibe ningun callback
- A la funcion no se le pasa otra funcion

Ahora bien, ten en cuenta que podemos realizar callbacks tanto usando `funciones flecha` como `funciones normales`.

entonces cual seria un ejemplo de callback en este caso?

Con tu ejemplo no es posible hacer un callback, por este motivo creare un pequeño ejemplo acerca de callbacks:

```js
window.onload = () => {
 
  //Callback
  function sayHiBeforeHello(){
    console.log("Hi!");
  }
  
  //Funcion que recibe y ejecuta el callback
  function sayHello(callback){
    callback();
    console.log("Hello world!");
  }
  
  //Ejecucion del callback
  sayHello(sayHiBeforeHello);

}
```

Este mismo ejemplo aplica a las funciones flechas, aqui el mismo ejemplo pero con funciones flecha:

```js
window.onload = () => {
 
  //Callback (flecha)
  const sayHiBeforeHello = () => console.log("Hi!");
  
  //Funcion flecha que recibe y ejecuta el callback
  const sayHello = callback => {
    callback();
    console.log("Hello world!");
  }
  
  //Ejecucion del callback
  sayHello(sayHiBeforeHello);

}
```

Ahora bien, hay que tener cuidado con los callbacks ya que como curiosidad tenemos algo llamado **callback hell** que se ve mas o menos asi:

[image: CallbackHell]

Porsupuesto nunca se debe llegar a tener un `callback hell` y de hecho actualmente existe algo llamado promises que evitan el uso excesivo de `callbacks` para no caer en el callback hell, el infierno de los callbacks.

Espero haya quedado lo mas claro posible esto de los callbacks.

Comment: si, de hecho me quedo mas claro el tema de las funciones flecha y callback , muchas gracias

Comment: De nada amigo, recuerda que si mi respuesta te fue de ayuda puedes darle al boton que parece un chulo para dar mi respuesta como aceptada.