# Fetch no asigna resultado

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch, promesas

Tengo un fetch que manda a llamar una lambda de AWS, este devuelve un objeto que tiene ciertos parametros que utilizo, principalmente uno llamado `Status` que es un boleano. La cuestión es que sin importar que haga con el fetch, este no me devuelve el resultado que necesito, pero con el `.then(data => console.log(data))` si me imprime el resultado

```
  async checkUser(){
    let url = <link>;
    let response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        User: this.Username
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));//Sii imprime el resultado necesitado
    console.log(response);//Imprime -Undefine-
    return response;
  }
```

No se que puedo estar haciendo mal, porque tengo otros fetch que los uso exactamente igual y si funcionan como debería, alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás mezclando conceptos. Si utilizas `async` y `await` ya no necesitas `.then()`, y como en tu caso quieres tener una función que devuelva una respuesta, debes decantarte por lo primero:

```
async checkUser() {
    let url = < link > ;
    let request = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            User: this.Username
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });
    let response = await request.json();
    
    return response;
}
```

Como aclaración, si utilizas `.then()` tendrás que trabajar dentro de la respuesta:

```
fetch(url, { /*params*/ }).then(request => request.json()).then(response => { /* ... */});
```

Comment: Porque ya no necesito el `.then()`?? Digo, pensaba que era literal, al obtener algo de internet, *luego* hacer tal cosa, y así

Comment: Gracias!! Aunque sigo sin entender porque en los otros fetch que tengo, no me da problemas hacerlo como muestro aquí

Comment: Te lo iba a explicar, pero ya lo hizo alguien mejor de lo que lo iba a hacer yo aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/277693/115064