# Promise, .then(), Javascript

Tags: javascript, promesas

Estoy aprendiendo a aplicar Promise. Simulo que obtengo datos desde un servidor. Datos en const lista. con el .then() los obtengo en listaNueva. pero los datos no se guardan ahi, no puedo iterar en lista nueva. Intente dentro del .then() pushear lista a listaNueva. Concatenar. Pero no funciono. Como podria guardar los datos en mi lista local listaNueva e iterarlos desde ahi?

```
//emula a un servidor
const lista=[{name:"john", age:10, id:1},
            {name:"clark", age:12, id:2},
            {name:"mili", age:14, id:3},]

//tomo  los datos
const getData=new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
  return resolve (lista)
},2000)
  })

getData.then((listaNueva)=>{
  console.log(listaNueva)
})

//quisiera iterar en listaNueva y trabajar los datos localmente
listaNueva.map(item=>{
 console.log(item)}
```

Comment: Acabo de copiar y pegar los datos en un jsfiddle, y el resultado de la promesa se muestra correctamente en la consola. También pude imprimir cada elemento en un `.forEach()`. Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Hola. agregue una edicion, cuando quiero trabajar los datos de listaNueva fuera de la funcion .then, no puedo. Lei que solo existen los datos dentro de la funcion.
Lo que yo quisiera es obtener los datos del servidor, guardarlos en una lista local para poder iterarlos y luego mostrarlos en un html. Aunque como estoy aprendiendo desconzco si la metodologia de trabajo es asi.

Comment: o quizas deberia trabajarlo todo dentro del .then
o dentro del .then pushear a una lista fuera de la funcion, aunque eso no resulto

Comment: Debés retornar la lista nueva y asignarla a una variable.

Comment: Pues, no hay nada de malo en crear una copia local. Sólo crea la variable que la contenga y la asignas en el then

Comment: algo asi?
let a=getData.then((listaNueva)=>{
 return listaNueva
 //a=listaNueva
  })

console.log("a",a)
me trae promise peding, el a fuera del .then. 
o si hago a=listaNueva dentro de la funcion then, tampoco funciona
quizas lo mejor sea trabajar todo dentro del .then

Comment: @Nam La resulción de la promise es asincronica, esto quiere decir para trabajar con los datos que serán obtenidos en algún momento en el futuro tenes que, o pocesarlos dentro del `.then` o usar [`await/async`](https://es.javascript.info/async-await). Puede que [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/277690/16597) te sea de ayuda

Answer (score -1):

Podria sera algo asi:

```
const lista=[{name:"john", age:10, id:1},
            {name:"clark", age:12, id:2},
            {name:"mili", age:14, id:3},]

const getData=new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
  return resolve (lista)
},2000)
  })

getData.then((listaNueva)=>{
  listaNueva.map(el => console.log(el))
})
```