# ¿Está bien usar una solicitud Ajax dentro de otra?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Me interesa saber si puedo hacerlo sin que a la futura comience a dar fallos y tener que cambiar todo a último momento...

Lo hago de esta forma ya que la primera solicitud me entrega un token y con la segunda lo descifro

```javascript
$.ajax({

  url: "...",
  data: {},
  type: "GET",

  success: function() {

    $.ajax({

    url: "...",
    data: {},
    type: "GET",

    etc...

    });

  },

  error: function() {}

});
```

Comment: Yo usaría promesas para evitar demasiada anidación, pero no hay problema en tener dependencias entre llamadas (necesitar una respuesta para hacer una nueva petición). Tengo una respuesta que te puede interesar, ya que toca este tema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await/388941#388941

Comment: Me pregunto, ¿por qué necesitas descifrar el token en el cliente? ¿ocurre algo nuevo, en el cliente, después de solicitar el token? Eso sería lo único que justificaría descifrarlo del lado del cliente.