# Problema con el uso de promesas

Tags: api, fetch, promesas

Tengo el siguiente código `JavaScript` que consume la `API` de `OpenWeather` para la consulta del clima, el caso es que por alguna razón, la promesa que retorna `fetch` no esta funcionando como espero.

```js
function getWeather(cityName) {
    let apiKey = "1ecf95a266618ca42f55e043f5bb942a";
    let data = fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${apiKey}`)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response
            } else {
                throw new Error(`Error en la solicitud de clima de ${cityName}`)
            }
        })
    return data;
}

let city = "Caracas"
let weatherData = getWeather(city)
console.log(weatherData)
```

La idea es que `data` se almacene `response` pero en cambio, en el se esta almacenando la promesa en si. Como puedo resolver este problema?

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await

Comment: perdon por la ignorancia pero esto no devuelve un ReadableStream? lei en la documentacion que hay que usar cierta logica para que ese Readable Stream te de los datos que necesitas, mas alla de las promesas y eso, es cierto?

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego Si el body de la respuesta es un Blob (datos en binario), puedes leerlo así, pero en este caso es un documento JSON (texto) y no necesitas complicarte la vida. Puedes ver la documentación en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body)

Answer (score 5):

Por mucho que las promesas o la sintaxis intenten ocultarlo, cuando trabajas en modo asíncrono no puedes gestionar las respuestas de modo síncrono. Por tanto, necesitas hacer algo como

```js
function getWeather(cityName){
  let apiKey = "1ecf95a266618ca42f55e043f5bb942a";
  let data =  fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${apiKey}`)
  //parseamos la respuesta json, dentro de una promesa
  .then(response => response.json()) 
  .catch(error => {
    throw new Error(`Error en la solicitud de clima de ${cityName}`)
  })
  return data; //data es una promesa con un objeto
}

let city = "Caracas"
getWeather(city).then(weatherData => console.log(weatherData));
```

O, con async/await:

```js
async function getWeather(cityName){
  const apiKey = "1ecf95a266618ca42f55e043f5bb942a";
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${apiKey}`);
    
    const data = await response.json();
    //aquí decidí mostrar directamente el valor, en lugar de devolverlo.
    console.log(data);
    return data; // se devolverá como una promesa, porque la función es async
  } catch(error) {
    throw new Error(`Error en la solicitud de clima de ${cityName}`)
  }
  
}

let city = "Caracas"
let promesa = getWeather(city);
// usamos el resultado para lo que queramos
// promesa.then(datos => ...);
```

Answer (score -3):

Estas igualando `data` a todo el `fetch`. Puedes ejecutar el `fetch` y igualar la respuesta a `data`:

```
function getWeather(cityName){
    let apiKey = "1ecf95a266618ca42f55e043f5bb942a";
    let data = null;
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${apiKey}`).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok){
            data = response;
        } else{
            throw new Error(`Error en la solicitud de clima de ${cityName}`)
        }
    })
    return data;
}
let city = "Caracas"
let weatherData = getWeather(city)
console.log(weatherData)
```

O simplemente puedes devolver el valor de la respuesta:

```
function getWeather(cityName){
    let apiKey = "1ecf95a266618ca42f55e043f5bb942a";
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${apiKey}`).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok){
            return response
        } else{
            throw new Error(`Error en la solicitud de clima de ${cityName}`)
        }
    })
}
let city = "Caracas"
let weatherData = getWeather(city)
console.log(weatherData)
```

Comment: Ninguna de las dos soluciones me funcionan

Comment: Ambas soluciones intentan mezclar código asíncrono y código síncrono, lo que no puede funcionar

Comment: retorna `null` y `undefined` en ambos casos.

Comment: Esto no funciona porque el response sigue siendo una promesa para acceder a los datos del fetch necesitas llamar al método `json()` de la respuesta del fetch!