# ¿Cómo obtener resultados de Promesas en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Estoy tratando conectar un sistema web con un RouterBoard, he encontrado una libreria (`routeros-client`) que me ha servido mucho. Sin embargo trabaja con Promesas (no estoy muy familiarizado con ellas).

Les dejo un fracmento de código tomado de la pequeña documentación de libreria.

```
const RouterOSClient = require('routeros-client').RouterOSClient;

// Connection
const api = new RouterOSClient({
    host: RB_IP_ADDRESS,
    user: RB_USER,
    password: RB_PASSWORD
});

api.connect().then((client) => {
    client.menu("/system identity").getOnly().then((result) => {
        console.log(result.identity);
        api.close();
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    // Connection error
    console.log(err);
});
```

Como se observa en el ejemplo, los resultados de las promesas ahi resueltas, como los errores que maneja, los muestra en consola. Lo que busco es poder sacar esos resultados en valiables que pueda enviar a mi aplicación. He intentado envolver el código en otras funciones y solo veo en consola `<pending>` o `undefined`

```
const getData = (api) => {
  api.connect().then((r) =>
    r
      .menu("/ip address")
      .get()
      .then((r) => r)
      .then(() => api.close())
  ).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
    return err.message;
  });
}


console.log(getData(api))
```

He estado leyedo sobre las Promesas pero aun no logro entender como funcionan las respuestas de `routeros-client`

Comment: Prueba utilizando async y await

Comment: Lectura recomendada (pregunta relacionada con respuestas bastante elaboradas): https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await

Answer (score 4):

```
const getData = async (api) => {
  try {
    await api.connect();
    const r = await r.menu("/ip address").get();
    return r;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return err.message;
  } finally {
    await api.close();
  }
}
```

De esta manera puedes almacenas la respuesta en variables

Comment: Usar async y await parece resolver únicamente la parte de espera...pero al querer mostrar la respuesta de la función solo recibo AsyncFuntion. Sin embargo dentro de la función si muestro la variable r o el error en consola si se muestran correctamente los datos.