# Como funciona el async y cuando usarlo

Tags: typescript, promesas, async-await

Estoy teniendo algunos problemas al entender conceptualmente las promises y los asyncs/awaits y cuando usarlos.

Supongamos que tenemos un código sobre una página web que hace lo siguiente:

1. Escribir un carácter en esa página del libro
2. Borrar un carácter en esa página del libro
3. Cambiar de página.

Además supongamos que tenemos una base de datos que es accedida por el servidor donde tenemos las páginas del libro que estamos escribiendo y el texto que hay en ellas.

A mi entender las 3 funciones deberían ser un async, por ejemplo, tiene sentido que se haga de manera asyncrona el borrar un carácter de la página 1 y cambiar a la página 2. Mi problema viene cuando por ejemplo hacemos lo siguiente:

1. Borramos un carácter de la página 1
2. Cambiamos a la página 2
3. Volvemos a cambiar a la página 1

Ahora si la petición 3 se resuelve antes que la 1 tendría una página 1 que aún contiene el carácter que he borrado (y por lo tanto lo podría volver a borrar).
Pareceria que la solución sería mirar que para la página que vamos a abrir no tenga ninguna petición pendiente, pero entonces perderíamos la gracia del asyncrono (ya que al final siempre deberíamos esperar a que se resolviera la petición anterior antes de ejecutar la nueva, haciendo que fuera una especie de código síncrono).

Que estoy entendiendo mal?

Comment: Simple: son eventos relacionados. No puedes cambiar de página si un evento de borrar carácter no se ha completado (sea exitoso o no). Eso no tiene mucho que ver con la asincronia de las peticiones, sino con la lógica aplicada. En la vida real, ¿puedes cambiar de página mientras estás borrando un carácter? Si lo intentas seguramente la página termine rota.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await/388941#388941

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una confusión bastante común. La gran mayoria de los lenguajes de programación ejecutan el código de forma de secuencial, el `async` rompe está secuencialidad y el `await` lo corrige.

Tu tienes 3 funciones asíncronas que su resultado afecta al resultado de la siguiente función, por tanto debes corregir la secuencialidad usando `await`

```
await funcionAync1();
await funcionAync2();
await funcionAync3();
```

¿Pero porque usar `async/await` en algo naturalmente síncrono?

Porque en tu aplicación no solo corre el código que tu has programado, dependiendo del framework existen otras tareas que están en ejecución en ese mismo instante.

Por ejemplo, en el navegador, tienes toda la interfaz gráfica ejecutándose, y si `funcionAync1()` es un proceso pesado te va a congelar por un instante la interfaz gráfica. En el lado del servidor puede bloquearte otras solicitudes HTTP

En otras palabras: En general los lenguajes y/o frameworks, tienen una "cola" de tareas a ejecutar (en javascript se llama [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop)) y una función `async` permite pasar a otra tarea (que no es necesarimente un código que tu has escrito) y no bloquear el programa, por otro lado `await` permite esperar que se termine la ejecución de una tarea asincrona para mantener la secuencialidad de TU código.

Comment: Tu explicación no me convence. Y no estoy troleando. Algo falla en tu lógica.

Comment: @ElTroll Un troll que dice "Y no estoy troleando.", está trolleando seguro

Comment: @ElTroll Debo romper una lanza en favor de Yussef y decir que a mi su explicación me parece bastante verosímil, eso si, desde mi ignorancia en el tema

Comment: Sin ánimo de polemizar y atendiendo al escenario que plantea el OP, los eventos se disparan sin depender uno de otro, es lo que motiva la duda de la asincronía de las operaciones y los eventos que desencadenan dichas operaciones. En la respuesta de Yussef, se muestra cada operación secuencialemente dentro de una función asíncrona, cosa que estaría bien si un sólo evento o acción de usuario dispara la misma, pero no es el caso, ya que claramente se trata de 3 eventos diferentes, por lo cual no podrías empaquetarlos en la misma llamada `async`. De allí mi comentario. Saludos

Comment: @ElTroll Es que me parece que el fondo de la pregunta no es el que señalas, como yo entendí la pregunta el problema es más abstracto, y apunta a entender el beneficio de usar funciones asíncronas aun cuando requieras una secuencialidad de instrucciones, esto se ve reflejado cuando el OP dice `...perderíamos la gracia del asyncrono (ya que al final siempre deberíamos esperar a que se resolviera la petición anterior antes de ejecutar la nueva...`

Comment: Repito, y es mi opinión, el problema no es de asincronía o si la asincronía tiene sentido o no. El problema es de lógica. Pretender hacer lo que pide el OP, sin tomar en cuenta la verosimilitud de la asincronía, es un error. Se convierte en un problema de lógica, un *pitfall* en el que caes cuando no comprendes que las operaciones asíncronas, inevitables en muchas aplicaciones, deben manejarse adecuadamente. Hacer uso de `async` y `await` no rompe esta asincronía, sólo la esconde o empaqueta

Comment: @Cram245 Favor aclarar el fondo de la pregunta

Comment: @Yussef En efecto com tu citas, la finalidad de la pregunta es resolver la duda del porque se usa el async si al final siempre le debemos meter un await haciendolo a efectos prácticos una función "síncrona".
El ejemplo que puse de app es uno ya precisamente escojido para ser degenerado y que surguiera el problema en caso de dejar actuar el async como un "verdadero async" (es decir sin ponerle un await y hacerlo "síncrono")

Answer (score 0):

Es un estilo de escritura de código `async`, se puede usar para escribir código en secuencia o el contrario es usar las funciones de continuación `then`, pero lo que describes de `conceptual` es mas complejo.

Sugiero revisar temas relacionados a como funciona JS en el browser.

Las `callbacks` de las promesas se registran como `micro-tareas` en la `lista de micro-tareas`.

Como sea que estuviese escrito el programa en JS, el `call stack` debe estar vacío para que se ejecuten las funciones `callback` que están en la `lista de micro-tareas`.

Además tienen orden de ejecución, por lo que esta situación que mencionas nunca va a pasar:

> Ahora si la petición 3 se resuelve antes que la 1 tendría una página 1 que aún contiene el carácter que he borrado

Asumiendo lo siguiente del programa:

- escribo/borro un carácter y se ejecuta una función que registra un callback a lista de tareas, `fn1`
- cambio de pagina y ejecuto una función que registra un callback a lista de tareas, `fn2`
- regreso a pagina anterior y la información esta actualizada (por medio de n mecanismo del componente), `fn3` a lista de tareas

También, puede que el call stack ya se haya vaciado entre cualquiera de los pasos descritos con anterioridad y por último la situación que propones donde los 3 pasos son peticiones async.

Ya se vacío el call stack, a continuación el orden de ejecución de las `callbacks` registradas la `lista de micro-tareas` es:

> [fn1, fn2, fn3]...

Este orden no cambia una vez registradas las callbacks, `fn1` va primero y así...

Se puede experimentar con el comportamiento de las promesas con los [métodos de la API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#promise_concurrency) a este problema se le conoce como el problema de `concurrency`.