# Async Await sin promesas

Tags: javascript, promesas, async-await

El objetivo de mi codigo es realizar una iteración de emoticonos, almacenados en un array, donde se muestre de forma similar a una slot.

El problema me ha surgido cuando mientras me iteraba las imagenes, pasaba a la siguiente seccion del codigo sin esperar a que terminase la iteracion. Al final la solución que he conseguido es la siguiente que os voy a mostrar.

Mi pregunta final es : si hay alguna manera de utilizar await async sin necesidad de promesas, ya que la respuesta de la promesa no la utilizo para nada.

```
        <div class="container-main">
            <div class="main-player mm">
                <div class="player__img-container ic">
                    <p class="pic pic-player">&#x270A</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-cpu mm">
                <div class="cpu__img-container ic">
                    <p class="pic pic-cpu">&#x270A</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```javascript
const emoticonos = ['&#x1F5FF', '&#x1F4C4', '&#x2702'];
async function movimiento(index){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            picCpu.innerHTML = emoticonos[index];
            picPlayer.innerHTML = emoticonos[index];
            resolve();
        }, 100)
    });
}


async function resultados(){
    let index = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        await movimiento(index).then(res => console.log(res));
        index++;
        if(index === 3){
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    let resultadoPlayer = aleatorio();
    let resultadoCpu = aleatorio();
    picPlayer.innerHTML = emoticonos[resultadoPlayer];
    picCpu.innerHTML = emoticonos[resultadoCpu];
    return [resultadoPlayer, resultadoCpu];
}`
```

Comment: Aunque no uses el resultado de la promesa, si la funcion devuelve una promesa, solo ignora el resultado... de esa forma la estas usando, pero sin importar lo que devuelve...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué diferencias hay entre callbacks, promises y async/await?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await)

Comment: Para qué quieres usar async await si no usas promesas?? No tiene sentido ninguno. async await se usan precisamente para evitar el llamado *"callback hell"* que producía trabajar con promesas y callbacks. No quieres usar promesas? Genial, pero si no usas promesas ni nada asíncrono no tiene sentido ninguno usar async o await.

Comment: @Benito-B Antes de realizar este código, estaba utilizando un setInterval para la muestra de distintas imagenes cada x milisegundos. La cuestión es que la ejecución del programa seguía independientemente de que el setInterval estuviese en curso. Creo que esto es lógico. Por lo tanto la unica manera que he conseguido ha sido esta. De que otra manera si no, podria esperar la ejecución de una acción que tarda tantos segundos como yo le he indicado sin que el flujo del programa siga?

Comment: Usa el enlace [edit] y añade un [mre] con tu problema exacto, porque si no es imposible ayudarte. El código que tienes ahí no hace absolutamente nada si lo ejecuto, danos las herramientas para poder ayudarte. Empezando por un [mre] funcional, siendo html, css y js puros puedes usar un fragmento de código de SO y podremos verlo y editarlo aquí mismo. Si no, no sé exactamente qué pretendes que hagamos sin siquiera saber el html que tienes.