# Esperar respuesta(return) de un callback

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, callback

Estoy intentando ejecutar el siguiente código. La lógica es la siguiente: Ejecutar "const mv" la cual dentro se ejecuta un un callback y dentro de ese callback se ejecuta función "aws" la cual también tiene un callback y quiero recoger el resultado de la función aws para continuar el código. Sin embargo no consigo recibir el return de aws. Como podría hacer? Gracias de antemano!!

Ejecuto método put el cual quiero que me devuelva el enlace de la cloud donde guardé file. Primero lo guardo en mi api( mv() ), una vez guardado ejecuto los métodos relacionados con la subida a la cloud dentro de la misma promesa y que a su vez tiene la siguiete promesa.

No sé si hay alguna forma mas funcional de hacerlo. Si alguien sabe, estoy abierto a aprender!! También espero que a alguien le pueda servir de orientación.

Typescript, nodejs,

función1

```
export const mv = async (file:any) => {


    //validaciones

    file.mv(path, async (err:any) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log('if',err);
            return {
                status: false,
                message: 'Subida fallida en el server local'
            }
        }
    
      const awsResult = await aws(fileName)
// Obtener resultado de la función aws(fileName)
      console.log(awsResult.status);

    })
```

función2

```
export const aws = async (fileName:any) => {

    let location;

      var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    s3.upload(params, function (err:any, data:any) {
        //handle error
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
          return {
              status: false,
              massage: err
          }
        }
      
        //success
        if (data) {
          console.log("Uploaded in:", data.Location);
          location = data.Location
         return {
            status: true,
            message: data.Location
         }
        }
      });
}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÖN**

```
    app.put('/upload', (request:any, response:any) => {
    
        var file = request.files.imagen;
        var type = request.params.type || 'color';
        var id = request.params.id || '1'
    
        const mvSave = mv(file, type, id).then( (result:any) => {
            console.log(result);
        })
       
        
    })

    export const mv = (file:any, type:any, id:any) => {
    
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    
        var fileSplit = file.name.split('.');
        var extensionFile = fileSplit[fileSplit.length - 1];
        var fileName = `${uuidv4()}.${extensionFile}`;
        let path = (`./uploads/${fileName}`);
        let typesAvailable = ['color', 'product'];
        var extensionFile = fileSplit[fileSplit.length - 1];
        var extensionAvailable = ['png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg'];
    
        //validaciones
    
        if (!file) {
            return {
                status: false,
                mensaje: 'No files'
            }
        }
    
        if (typesAvailable.indexOf(type) < 0) {
            return {
                ok: false,
                mensaje: 'tipos de colección no válidos',
                errors: { message: 'Tipo de colección no es válida' }
            };
        }
    
        if (extensionAvailable.indexOf(extensionFile) < 0) {
            return {
                ok: false,
                mensaje: 'Extension no valida'
            }
        }
    
        
    
            file.mv(path, async (err:any) => {
    
                if (err) {
                    console.log('if',err);
                    return {
                        status: false,
                        message: 'Subida fallida en el server local'
                    }
                }
            
                const awsResult =  aws(fileName, type).then( (result:any) => {
                    return resolve({
                        tatus: true,
                        message: result.message
                    })
                })
            })
        })
}


export const aws = (fileName:any, type:AnyARecord) => {

    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {

        AWS.config.update({**config**  });
    
        var params = {**propiedades**};
    
        const uploadAWS = upload(params,fileName).then( (result:any) => {
            return resolve({
                tatus: true,
                message: result.message
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes devolver una promesa con los valores que buscas, pero no te vale con poner async: necesitas indicar qué y cuándo se va a devolver lo que quieres usando el constructor de promesas.
No he podido probar el código (estoy en móvil), pero debería ser algo parecido a esto

```
export const aws = (fileName:any) => {
  return new Promise(function(success, error) {
    let location;

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    s3.upload(params, function (err:any, data:any) {
        //handle error
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
          return error({
              status: false,
              massage: err
          });
        }
      
        //success
        if (data) {
          console.log("Uploaded in:", data.Location);
          location = data.Location
         return success ({
            status: true,
            message: data.Location
         }) 
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Gracias a tu ayuda he conseguido lo que necesitaba. Concatenar 3 funciones asíncronas y devolver un resultado final. Ahora por aprendizaje, sabrías decirme si esto se puede hacer con async o await? Más por quedarme con la lógica de uso que con código. GRACIAS POR LA AYUDA Pablo!!

Comment: No se me ocurre como escribirlo con async, pero piensa que async/await no es más que *azúcar sintáctico* para las promesas. Hay veces que tienes que usar una sintaxis más flexible aunque sea menos elegante

Comment: Si quieres profundizar en el asunto, busca información en MDN (Mozilla Developer Network, pero te dejo una pregunta/respuesta relacionada que puede servir para entender esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243352/secuencia-de-retornos-incorrecta-usando-async-await

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Muy ilustrativo!!