# ¿Porque imprime mi variable array como vacia?

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs

estoy aprendido a usar node js y me genera dudas cuando quiero hacer un `console.log()` tengo un foreach en donde adentro tiene un `settimeout(2000)` cuando lo corro me imprime la consola intente con async await pero no tuve resultado ¿hay alguna manera de que me imprima el resultado del arreglo o comprobar que el settimeout ya termino?

esto es lo que eh avanzado

```
async function marcas(id_marcas) {
let array = [];
await id_marcas.forEach(async element => {
    setTimeout( () => {
        array.push(element);
    }, 2000);
});
console.log(array)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas erróneas en ese código:

- La función forEach de Array no es asíncrona y además no devuelve nada, por lo que ese `await` es ignorada aunque la función que le pases sea `async`.
- Se están creando N timeouts, donde N es la longitud de `id_marcas` y no uno. Pero estás pidiendo que todos se ejecuten a la vez dentro de 2 segundos.
- `console.log(array)` se ejecuta inmediatamente después de "encolar" los N timeouts, por lo que el array está aún vacío.

```js
async function marcas(id_marcas) {
  let array = [];
  await id_marcas.forEach(async element => {
    console.log("creando el timeout");
    setTimeout( () => {
        console.log("ejecutando el push");
        array.push(element);
    }, 2000);
  });
  console.log("el array tiene",array);
}

marcas([1,2,3,4]);
```

Podrías esperar para ver el resultado:

```js
async function marcas(id_marcas) {
  let array = [];
  id_marcas.forEach(element => {
    console.log("creando el timeout");
    setTimeout( () => {
        console.log("ejecutando el push");
        array.push(element);
    }, 2000);
  });
  setTimeout( () => {
    console.log("el array tiene",array);
  }, 2100);
}

marcas([1,2,3,4]);
```

Puedes echar un vistazo a esta pregunta y respuesta para entender mejor las Promesas y async/await usando timeouts: [Secuencia de retornos incorrecta usando async/await](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243352/secuencia-de-retornos-incorrecta-usando-async-await/243367#243367)

Comment: gracias si me ayudo

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario las funciones asincronas para lo que estas haciendo. Te propongo la siguiente solucion:

```
function marcas(id_marcas) {
  let array = [];
  id_marcas.forEach(element => {
    setTimeout(array.push(element),100)
  })
  return array
}

console.log(marcas([12,13]))
```

En tu codigo habia un pequeño error y es que el setTimeout debe ser asi:

```
setTimeout(array.push(element), 2000);
```

PD: supongo que tu intencion es meter en array cada elemento del array id_marcas que pasas como parametro

Espero que te ayude. Un saludo

Comment: No, `setTimeout(array.push(element), 2000);` es incorrecto. Es equivalente a hacer: `let a = array.push(element); setTimeout(a, 2000);` donde `a` es la longitud del array (un número)

Comment: Lo probé, pero no funciono, aun así tu código y el del Sr.Pablo me ayudo para resolverlo mucho mejor, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme lo mismo digo para el Sr.Pablo